# gcloud sdk fails on yum update fresh centos7 running on GCE

Tags: centos, centos7, gcloud

If I create a google compute engine instance, selecting centos 7 as the image, ssh to the instance, and run `yum update -y`, I see the following error:

```
  Updating   : google-cloud-sdk-147.0.0-1.el7.noarch                                                         37/75 
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'module' object has no attribute 'GetJobDirFlag'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Compiling platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2/__init__.py ...
  File "platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2/__init__.py", line 347
    print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

warning: %post(google-cloud-sdk-147.0.0-1.el7.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package google-cloud-sdk-147.0.0-1.el7.noarch
```

I have tried it a couple of times and it is 100% repeatable I would expect for anyone. Should I just ignore this error? If not, what steps should I take? I'm typically a fedora user however google cloud does not have a fedora image so I'm using CentOS as a total CentOS newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the problem and everything seems to work correctly after the update, it should be safe to just ignore the error.